# dojo web application requesting WCF service

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, jsonp

I have setup a WCF service that returns json format data with my configuration file setup as follows:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" name="Services.Service1">
    <endpoint address="mex" 
      binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJsonP" 
      contract="Services.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

My service WebInvoke function:

```
 <OperationContract()>
 <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,       Responseformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Function RetrieveData(ByVal screenName As String) As Stream
```

And Finally my dojo based website's function to call the webservice:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      dojo.ready(function () {
        dojo.io.script.get({                  url: 
          "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/Services/Service/Service1.svc/GetData?item=Tweet",
            callbackParamName: "callback",
            content: { username: "me", password: "you" }
             }).then(function (data){
                   return data.results;
               })
    });


 </script>
```

The problem is that I cannot get the data to flow through to the dojo application. First I get the error callback undefined. Now I am not sure if I am clear on this callback thing: is it the name of the function in the dojo application as I have above but the function is not named or is it the name of the function the returns the json response in the web service which by the way is installed on a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do with .NET:

My service:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetMyStuff", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public String GetMyStuff()
        {
            var myStuff = getFromService("foo");

            return new { label = "name", identifier = "Id", items = myStuff.Select(w => new { Id = w.Id, name = w.Description }) }.ToJSON();
        }
```

I use this `ToJSON()` helper function declared as this:

```
public static class LinqUtils
{
        public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
}
```

In web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Services/StuffServiceJson.svc" service="MyStuff.MyStuffService" />  <!-- This is an actual URL mapping to your service endpoint -->
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

<!-- other stuff -->

    <services>
        <service name="MyStuff.MyStuffService">
           <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyStuff.MyStuffService" address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"/> <!-- This is a service endpoint to your implementation class mapping -->
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In Dojo:

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr"], function(xhr) {

xhr.get({
                                url: "/Services/StuffServiceJson.svc/GetMyStuff",
                                handleAs: "json",
                                preventCache: true
    }).then(function (data) {
            //Do something with DATA
    }, function (error) {
                //Do something with error OMG
    });

});
```

If you get a problem with the data being returned as string anyway (happens in .NET sometimes) then you're gonna have to take your data and do

```
require(["dojo/json"], function(json){
    json.parse(data)
});
```

Luck,

Comment: thanks for your response. But doesn't xhr not work for cross domain server applications

Comment: See this link http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Cross-domain-XMLHttpRequest-with-Dojo-td1864416.html and look at Kris Zyp's response.